# Animate UIButton Down - Xcode

Tags: ios, uibutton, jquery-animate, ibaction

I wanted to know how I would go about animating a UIButton down when clicked via

```
-(IBAction)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. What goes into the ibaction that will animate the button down?

Comment: What do you mean by "animating a UIButton down"? Do you mean animating the button's frame to a new position?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside your `IBAction`

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

//animates button 25 pixels right and 25 pixels down. Customize
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x + 25, button.frame.origin.y + 25, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     [button setFrame:newFrame];
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

EDIT - To toggle between frames

initialize boolean `clicked` to NO somewhere

```
if (!clicked){

    //animates button 25 pixels right and 25 pixels down. Customize
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x + 25, button.frame.origin.y + 25, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         [button setFrame:newFrame];
                     }
                     completion:nil];

     clicked = YES;

} else {


    //animates button 25 pixels left and 25 pixels up. Customize
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x - 25, button.frame.origin.y - 25, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         [button setFrame:newFrame];
                     }
                     completion:nil];

    clicked = NO;

}
```

Comment: How could I Put this in a if else statement so when the button is first clicked it moves position, then when clicked again it moves back up

Comment: If you're just toggling back and forth you could check the buttons frame in your conditional, or set a boolean flag

Comment: Ok...I have no clue how to put this in boolean. Could You please please edit the answer to include it?

Comment: Wow. This is great. But i still get an error when I am trying to initialize boolean to NO.

Comment: Use of unidentified identifier "clicked". This is my first experience with boolean so I appreciate your patience.

Comment: add `{}` brackets after `yourViewController()` at the top of your .m file and in those brackets put `BOOL clicked;`. Then in viewDidLoad add the line `clicked = NO;`

Comment: Also Boolean's and boolean logic are very important to programming and development in any language, so I would advise you to read up on that and some other basic stuff before you try and do anything too complex, you'll just keep getting yourself frustrated. :)