# Scene transition of SKScene with UIKit elements (UIButtons, UILabel, ...)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, sprite-kit

I have a menu which is a SKScene with a SKSpriteNode as as background and with 3 UIButtons and 1 UILabel.

When the user clicks the button, this scene transition is triggered :

```
view?.presentScene(GameScene(size: view!.bounds.size), transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(2))
```

The scene does change (the background changes) but all my UIElements are still in place.
Is there a proper way to remove them along the scene transition ? By proper way I mean that the garbage collector should at some point free the menu scene from the memory (which cannot be done if there are still UIElements on it).

Comment: I am assuming your UIKit elements were added to the view. If you want them to disappear, you'll need to remove them from the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here. First is to keep using the UIKit elements and actively removing them when transitioning to your game scene. For example, you can set up a method for doing the same when the button for the game is pressed:

```
func hideButtons () {
    //Hide your buttons and label here.
    btn.hidden = true //Either hide it
    btn.removeFromSuperview() //or remove it altogether.
    ... 
}
```

And then call this method just before you present the scene.

```
self.hideButtons()
view?.presentScene(GameScene(size: view!.bounds.size), transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(2))
```

Alternatively, you can implement a button in the SKScene itself, using the touch delegates.

Declare a SKSpriteNode with the same frame as your button. When you detect a touch on the button, trigger the scene change.

Another option is using a class like [AGSpriteButton](https://github.com/akashgupta88/AGSpriteButton). It has a setup system very similar to that of a UIButton.

Comment: Thxs ZeMoon. If I hide the buttons, it is to "unhide" them when the user goes back to the menu scene. How can I achieve the "go back" transition ? Do I need a global var `menuScene` accessible in each of my view files (from where I can go back to the menu) ?

Comment: For that you need a way for the SKScene to communicate with the UIViewController. Have a look at this answer to see how to achieve the same: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27099631/2043580

Answer (score 1):

If you want the buttons to be released then you will have to remove them from the view.

It is worth considering though if this really necessary?  Is the amount of memory reclaimed worth the additional cost to re-add these buttons later? assuming you can return to the menu.

There are a few options for making a visually appealing transition using both SpriteKit and UIKit elements.  Although I wouldn't necessarily recommend them.

1. Animate the buttons off screen manually, by adjusting the [frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17820450/1721611) or [alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8047622/1721611).
2. Remove the transition from the SKScene and animate a transition of the UIView using [transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:)
    or [transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:)

If you can't create an effect using either of these options that is satisfactory then it is probably worth reimplementing your scene/view to use only SpriteKit elements.

Comment: If I hide the elements to display them back when the user returns to menu scene, how do I actually "pop" the level scene to go back to the menu ? I have to `presentScene` right ? But that will override the first menu scene instance ?

Comment: Your SKScene class should not be directly responsible for any UIKit views, traditionally this is the responsibility of the UIViewController, so you should not have any issues if your MenuScene is released, and then another reallocated when you return to the menu in your app.  Upon returning to the menu you will have tell your view controller to animate the display of your UIKit views again.  This is a pain and one reason why I would recommend a pure SpriteKit approach if possible.  It is also probably better to encapsulate all related logic into either separate scenes or view controllers.